# Determining if a given function is a closed loop

Tags: geometry, graphing-functions, area

Is there any method/way to determine if a given maths function in $x$ and $y$, when plotted with the help of coordinate-axes, forms a *closed-loop*? In other words, does it, all by itself, enclose some area?

For example,
$x^2+y^2=5$
forms a closed loop (a circle).

But $y = x^2$
does not form a closed loop (as it is a parabola, and is *open* from above).

Comment: Unbounded curves (like parabolas) cannot be closed. Smooth enough curves whose parametric representation is periodic are closed, but checking for periodicity is not always straightforward.

Comment: Yes...checking for periodicity is indeed difficult, but is there any proof for this fact (that  curves whose parametric representation is periodic are closed)?  Also, what exactly is meant by *smooth enough curves?*

Comment: If, as in your examples, your curve is quadratic, i.e., it can be written as $A x^2 + 2 B x y + C y^2 + D x + E y + F = 0$ for some coefficients $A, \ldots, F$, then the curve is bounded iff $AC - B^2 > 0$, though this case includes empty curves like $x^2 + y^2 + 1 = 0$; excluding degeneracies these curves are exactly the ellipses.

Comment: @TravisWillse That is helpful...thanks, but I am asking for a general case, I have given examples of 2nd-degree equations as they are easier to visualize

Comment: @CoolCoder If the parametric representation is periodic, then the curve returns to the same point after each period then retraces the same curve. "Smooth enough" was primarily meant to exclude "pathological" functions. Continuously differentiable would be sufficient though not necessary, depending also on the exact definitions you use for a "curve".

Comment: @CoolCoder Do you really want arbitrary curves $F(x, y) = 0$, or are you restricting to curves where $F$ is a polynomial?

Comment: @dxiv, the idea of using parametric form of the function seems very interesting....thank you!

Comment: @TravisWillse, yes, I mean this for arbitrary curves $F(x, y) = 0$

Comment: An indirect criteria : a (sufficiently regular) curve is bounded iff it encloses a finite area, i.e., if the integral giving this area is finite (convergent). This is easy to do with parametric equations.

Answer (score 3):

The circle $x^2+y^2-5=0$ and the parabola $y-x^2=0$ are special cases of plane algebraic curves $p(x,y)=0$ where $p$ is a polynomial in two variables, and those in turn are special cases of zero-sets or loci of $f(x,y)=0$ where $f$ is any function $f:\mathbb{R}^2\to\mathbb{R}$.

In general, you can check whether the locus is a “closed loop” by verifying that it is a compact, connected 1-manifold.

The “compact” part boils down to “bounded” (I’m assuming that $f$ is continuous, so the inverse image $f^{-1}(0)$ is closed.) You need to see that $f(x,y)=0$ forces $|x|$ and $|y|$ not to exceed some fixed bound $B$. This is often, but not always, relatively easy to do by studying the behavior of $f$ for fixed values of $x$ or $y$.

The “1-manifold” part is usually handled by something like the Implicit Function Theorem. If $f$ is differentiable and the derivatives $\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}$ and $\frac{\partial f}{\partial y}$ don’t simultaneously vanish whenever $f(x,y)=0$, then the conditions of the Implicit Function Theorem are met and the locus is locally one-dimensional, namely, a curve. Singularities need to be explored further to determine if they still describe a topological curve (they may or they may not.)

The “connected” part may be the hardest. There’s no simple general procedure to apply: you need to study the locus and check that you can travel from any point to any other point. Tools from algebraic topology are sometimes applicable, but usually it’s easier to find a specific reason given the specific nature of the given function $f$.